# Configuring angular bundling

Tags: angular, typescript, transpiler

I'm currently using AoT angular type of transpiler. The result is the minified and bundled javascript.

**CURRENT BEHAVIOUR:**

For example, if the project (file structure) looks like this:

```
src/
    app/
        component1.ts
        component2.ts
        component3.ts
        ...
        myImportantComponent.ts
    main.ts
    polyfills.ts
    ...
```

by **default** options, it will get transpiled into something like this:

```
src/
    app/
        1-es5.<hash>.js
        1-es2015.<hash>.js
        2-es5.<hash>.js
        2-es2015.<hash>.js
        ...
    main-es2015.<hash>.js
    polyfills-es2015.<hash>.js
    ...
```

Note that "myImportantComponent.ts" gets bundled into of the "XX-es5.<hash>.js" (and XX-es2015.<hash>.js) files.

**QUESTION/DESIRED BEHAVIOUR:**

**My goal** is to **build** "myImportantComponent.ts" into a **separate file**, without any other file bundled with him (**file name** of resulting file is **not** **important** to me). Simply put, I want to achieve this:

```
src/
    app/
        1-es5.<hash>.js      <--rest of the application
        1-es2015.<hash>.js
        2-es5.<hash>.js
        2-es2015.<hash>.js
        ...
        myImportantFile-es2015.<hash>.js <--only contains data from myImportantFile.ts
    main-es2015.<hash>.js
    polyfills-es2015.<hash>.js
    ...
```

How to achieve that with angular transpiler?

Comment: What's the context - why is this something you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to replace only that file in production environment. Using environment variable, to detect if it's production environment, is not an option, because i don't have access to the data in the production environment. Current way, to find and change values in bundled and minified script, takes too long to deploy (because of possible errors in the process)

Comment: You can't do that anyways because even if you do lazy loading a reference to the minified file is kept in the main bundle which includes the generated hash in the name. This means that if you make a change and re-generate the files the hashes will have changed. It also means that if you decide to manually change the filename back to the previous one and deploy it not all clients might see it because of browser cash busting (filename = same so do not reload).

Comment: There are other ways to deal with that that might be simpler, if you can just extract *configuration* rather than implementation. Then you can load JSON at startup (see https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) or even use something like SSI (see https://github.com/spa-configuration/angular-ssi).